# What is the best way to compile JavaScript-like structures to static, fast C++?

Tags: javascript, c++, c, data-structures, compiler-construction

On the development of a compiler from a language very similar to JavaScript to C++, I need a way to represent data structures. JavaScript's main data structures are Arrays and Hash-Tables. Arrays are more straighforward: I can use a **vector of untyped pointers**. It needs to be a vector because JS arrays are dynamic, and of pointers because JS arrays can hold any kind of object, for example:

```
var array = [1,2,[3,4],"test"];
```

I can't see a way to represent this other than that (is there?). For the hashes, I could use something similar, except including the string hashing step on access.

The problem is: **JavaScript hashes are JIT-compiled into actual C++ objects which probably are much faster than hashes**. This way, I'm afraid my attempt to generate C++ like that will actually result in slower code than the JavaScript version!

1. Does that make sense?
2. What would be the best approach to my compiler?

Comment: How about simply replicating what JavaScript JIT compilers do and create hidden classes for common object patters? http://mrale.ph/blog/2012/06/03/explaining-js-vms-in-js-inline-caches.html

Comment: You've re-discovered one of the many reasons fast dynamic language implementations do adaptive optimizations at run time. An AOT compiler is ill-suited to these languages, period. If you want to compete with JIT compilers in this regard, don't write an AOT compiler.

Comment: You could use the Boost Variant or Any libraries for dynamic types without (necessarily) dynamic memory allocation. Or write your own discriminated union type, if you're feeling masochistic.

Comment: This right there is one of the reasons SO is such a powerful tool. For both the article and those comments, thanks! Very insightful. (Now I'm just thinking another structure I could use instead, that would be powerful without making coding difficult - it is my language so I don't **need** to have JS arrays, after all.)

Answer (score 0):

If this is an AOT compiler you can only process the hash keys that you see at compile-time, obviously. In this case you can change hash accesses to known keys to array accesses, giving each known key a small integer as index.

Comment: `function f(o) { return o.a; }; f({a: 1, b: 2}); f({a: 1, c: 2});`

Comment: In this case the compiler knows the keys `a`, `b` and `c` will always be accessed, and could transform the hashing into a simple offset access.

Comment: Which offset? You need different offsets for different sets of members. And since you propose an array, not an integer hash table, you'd have to reserve as many slots as attribute names are used in the whole program *for every object*. JIT compilers get away with it because they specialize code for specific object layouts, but an AOT compiler can't do that.

Comment: Oh, but in the example you gave `f` could be inlined in the call sites for those literals. Obviously this cannot be done everywhere and for every object.

Comment: Yes, the example was simplified because I couldn't be bothered to write a more complicated example.